# Does Cloud Run with a VPC Connector send all original outbound traffic through the connector?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-networking

With fully managed Cloud Run connected to a VPC with a [Serverless VPC Accessor](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc), does *all* outbound traffic from Cloud Run go through that connector, or only traffic destined for RFC 1918 addresses?

If only for private IPs, how can I configure Cloud Run to send all of its outbound requests into the VPC?

(Note - with Cloud Functions there is an option to route all traffic or only private IPs through the connector - [reference](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now the Serverless VPC Connector for Cloud Run is still on Beta and some Network features will be added in the future, including *Egress control*.

The goal right now is to develop an identical implementation as the one Cloud Functions has so it makes sense to quote [that doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings). Unfortunately there is no ETA for it to be implemented. We encourage you to follow up the release notes

When reading [this particular doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc) keep in mind: The Cloud Run service is the one fully managed, not the VPC Access connector. With that said, we could tell that all the traffic without would go through the VPC for now.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: Thanks!  But, my experiments seem to show that not all traffic egresses into the VPC.  It seems that only RFC 1918 addresses go into the VPC, while all others avoid the VPC.  Would you confirm that, indeed, all outbound traffic from managed Cloud Run routes through the connector?

Comment: What you say is correct for how the VPC connector works "today". What Kevin is saying is that with "egress controls", all egress traffic will be possible to flow through the VPC.

Comment: Got it.  To whit: Cloud Run only sends traffic bound for 1918 through the connector.
In the future, there will be an option to send all traffic through the connector.  Thanks all!